# Get and set value of TextField

Tags: ember.js

I have this code for view:

```js
App.TodoView = Em.View.extend({
    labelView: Em.TextField.extend({

    }),
    createNew:function () {
        console.log(this.labelView.get('value'));
    }
});
```

and this template:

```html
{{#view App.TodoView}}    
    {{view labelView}}    
    {{#view Em.Button target="parentView" action="createNew"}}Add{{/view}}    
{{/view}}
```

And I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object (subclass of Ember.TextField) has no method 'get'
```

I want to use insertNewLine method too, so I can set the value of the `Em.TextField` in template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining a class and trying to get the `value` from it. What you rather want is to get the `value` of a concrete instance. This can be achieved by binding the `value` of the `LabelView` to a value which can then be retrieved in the `App.TodoView`, in this case `todoLabel`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/PTPsV/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
{{#view App.TodoView }}
    <!-- Bind the value of the LabelView to todoLabel on the App.TodoView -->
    {{view LabelView valueBinding="todoLabel" }}
    {{#view Em.Button target="parentView" action="createNew" }}Add{{/view}}
{{/view}}
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.TodoView = Em.View.extend({
    LabelView: Em.TextField.extend(),

    createNew: function(){
        var value = this.get('todoLabel');
        console.log( 'le todoLabel', value );
    }
});​
```

Note that since you are defining a class `LabelView` it's a convention to write it in Uppercase, whereas instances are written in lowerCase. See a good blog post about naming convention by [The Emberist](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html).

Also, to access a property on an `Ember.Object`, you should always use `get`, so it's `this.get('todoLabel')` and not `this.todoLabel`.

---

You can now implement further methods like `insertNewline` and `cancel` - note it's `insertNewline` and not `insertNewLine`, see [text_support](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_support.js#L56).

The result would look like this, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/9ZLAC/:

```js
App.TodoView = Em.View.extend({
    LabelView: Em.TextField.extend({
        insertNewline: function(){
            this.get('parentView').createNew();
        },            
        cancel: function(){
            this.set('value', '');
        }
    }),

    createNew: function(){
        var value = this.get('todoLabel');
        console.log( 'le todoLabel', value );
    }
});​
```

Comment: thx a lot, great answer! may be my question was stupid but ember docs are sooo poor. hope they improve it.

Comment: Glad I could help. The documentation is improved continuously. Until then SO is a good resource for help.